# Else if statement not functioning properly

Tags: c++, if-statement, stack

I was solving the balanced parentheses problem using stack implementation when I came across this situation wherein I was using the 'else-if' statements to check for the closing braces but this gave a different output than the expected one. On changing all the 'else-if' statements to plain 'if' statements the code worked just fine.
I want to know why this happened because I always thought that using 'else-if' statements was a better practice.

```
int main(){
    stack<char> bracks;
    string s;   // input string: {a+(b+c-[e-f])*d}
    cin >> s;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        if(s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[')    bracks.push(s[i]);
        else if(s[i] == '}')
            if(bracks.top() == '{')    bracks.pop();
        else if(s[i] == ')')
            if(bracks.top() == '(')    bracks.pop();
        else if(s[i] == ']')
            if(bracks.top() == '[')    bracks.pop();
    }
    if(bracks.empty())  cout << "Balanced\n";
    else    cout << "Unbalanced\n";
}
```

Expected output for the input string : "{a+(b+c-[e-f])*d}" is "Balanced" but I'm getting "Unbalanced" as the output.

Answer (score 4):

> using 'else-if' statements was a better practice.

`if` and `else-if` are different things, which are used in different situations. Neither is better or worse.

Consider that code:

```
if (c1) if (c2) a else b
```

The way the compiler sees it is:

```
if (c1) {
    if (c2)
        a
    else
        b
}
```

The reason is that `else` always belongs to the innermost `if`.
In your case your conditions mean the following:

```
if(s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[') {
    bracks.push(s[i]);
} else if(s[i] == '}') {
    if(bracks.top() == '{') {
        bracks.pop();
    } else if(s[i] == ')') {
        if(bracks.top() == '(') {
            bracks.pop();
        } else if(s[i] == ']') {
            if(bracks.top() == '[') {
                bracks.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your indentation suggests that it's not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need some additional braces, so that `else` applies to the correct `if`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
    if(s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[')    bracks.push(s[i]);
    else if(s[i] == '}')
    {
        if(bracks.top() == '{')    bracks.pop();
    }
    else if(s[i] == ')')
    {
        if(bracks.top() == '(')    bracks.pop();
    }
    else if(s[i] == ']')
    {
        if(bracks.top() == '[')    bracks.pop();
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SJoAVwoUwwnyz2z2)

Indenting your code properly would help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the code within your `for` loop, which I quote here verbatim

> ```
>     if(s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[')    bracks.push(s[i]);
>     else if(s[i] == '}')
>         if(bracks.top() == '{')    bracks.pop();
>     else if(s[i] == ')')
>         if(bracks.top() == '(')    bracks.pop();
>     else if(s[i] == ']')
>         if(bracks.top() == '[')    bracks.pop();
> ```

has indentation that implies (to a human reader) a particular order.   However, the compiler ignores indentation.   If we were to use indentation (and a couple of additional line breaks) to make the code appear to us as it appears to the compiler we would get

```
    if(s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[')
        bracks.push(s[i]);
    else if(s[i] == '}')
        if(bracks.top() == '{')
            bracks.pop();
        else if(s[i] == ')')
            if(bracks.top() == '(')
                bracks.pop();
            else if(s[i] == ']')
                if(bracks.top() == '[')
                    bracks.pop();
```

So, we actually have three nested levels, where your indentation implied only one.  The thing is, since the compiler (mostly) ignores whitespace, these two samples of code are identical as far as the compiler is concerned.

Since humans interpret whitespace and compilers ignore it,  guidelines that are often considered good practice also involve adding `{}` to ensure code is logically grouped in a way that (hopefully) means a human and a compiler will interpret the code as having the same meaning.   For example, the following adds pairs of `{}` at the beginning and end of each nested if statement.

```
    if(s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[')
    {
        bracks.push(s[i]);
    }
    else if(s[i] == '}')
    {
        if(bracks.top() == '{')
        {
            bracks.pop();
        }
        else if(s[i] == ')')
        {
            if(bracks.top() == '(')
            {
                bracks.pop();
            }
            else if(s[i] == ']')
            {
                if(bracks.top() == '[')
                {
                    bracks.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This sample code has identical meaning to the yours, but (subjectively) it is easier for a mere human to tell which sections of code are grouped together.

The thing is, there are plenty of schemes for indenting code, and for placing curly braces.   And you will find advocates for some variations over others.   For example, the following is identical, except that it follows a rule that the opening `{` should be on the same line as the `if` statement it is associated with.

```
    if(s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[') {
        bracks.push(s[i]);
    }
    else if(s[i] == '}') {
        if(bracks.top() == '{') {
            bracks.pop();
        }
        else if(s[i] == ')') {
            if(bracks.top() == '(') {
                bracks.pop();
            }
            else if(s[i] == ']') {
                if(bracks.top() == '[') {
                    bracks.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Again, objectively, this code has identical meaning (as far as the compiler is concerned).  However, some people will advocate one, some will advocate the other.